# html2canvas изображения на другом домене

Tags: html5, canvas, html2canvas

Я использую библиотеку [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com), и до недавнего времени, пока использовал изображения с тогоже домена на котором находится скрипт все работало отлично. Если изменить домен с картинками (даже на поддомен), то они перестают отрисовываться.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Как быть в таком случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все, разобрался.

Там есть параметр `proxy`, в котором нужно указать файл через который будут проксироваться запросы, например

```
{ proxy: 'html2proxy.php'}
```

А уже непосредственно этот файл превращает картинки с другого сервера в `base64`

Неплохой пример прокси можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy)

Answer (score -1):

Стоит попробовать добавить к изображению заголовки, разрешающие обработку с нужного домена.

Comment: К изображению заголовки? это как? Поподробнее объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @DOC_tr, я про http-заголовки.

Comment: CORS в библиотеке тоже реализован, но включение его ничего не дало. Единственный вариант который я нашел, и который работает я описал в ответе. Но он работает не слишком шустро (хотя на момент отрисовки можно и подождать).